# Caffe HDF5 pixel-wise classification

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to implement a pixel-wise binary classification for images using caffe. For each image having dimension  3x256x256, I have a 256x256 label array in which each entry is marked as either 0 or 1. Also, when I read my HDF5 file using the below code,

```
dirname = "examples/hdf5_classification/data"

f = h5py.File(os.path.join(dirname, 'train.h5'), "r")
ks = f.keys()
data = np.array(f[ks[0]])
label = np.array(f[ks[1]])
print "Data dimension from HDF5", np.shape(data)
print "Label dimension from HDF5", np.shape(label)
```

I get the data and label dimension as

```
Data dimension from HDF5 (402, 3, 256, 256)
Label dimension from HDF5 (402, 256, 256)
```

I am trying to feed this data into the given hdf5 classification network and while training, I have the following output(using the default solver, but in GPU mode).

```
!cd /home/unni/MTPMain/caffe-master/ && ./build/tools/caffe train -solver examples/hdf5_classification/solver.prototxt
```

gives

> ```
> I1119 01:29:02.222512 11910 caffe.cpp:184] Using GPUs 0
> I1119 01:29:02.509752 11910 solver.cpp:47] Initializing solver from parameters: 
> train_net: "examples/hdf5_classification/train_val.prototxt"
> test_net: "examples/hdf5_classification/train_val.prototxt"
> test_iter: 250
> test_interval: 1000
> base_lr: 0.01
> display: 1000
> max_iter: 10000
> lr_policy: "step"
> gamma: 0.1
> momentum: 0.9
> weight_decay: 0.0005
> stepsize: 5000
> snapshot: 10000
> snapshot_prefix: "examples/hdf5_classification/data/train"
> solver_mode: GPU
> device_id: 0
> I1119 01:29:02.519805 11910 solver.cpp:80] Creating training net from train_net file: examples/hdf5_classification/train_val.prototxt
> I1119 01:29:02.520031 11910 net.cpp:322] The NetState phase (0) differed from the phase (1) specified by a rule in layer data
> I1119 01:29:02.520053 11910 net.cpp:322] The NetState phase (0) differed from the phase (1) specified by a rule in layer accuracy
> I1119 01:29:02.520104 11910 net.cpp:49] Initializing net from parameters: 
> name: "LogisticRegressionNet"
> state {
>   phase: TRAIN
> }
> layer {
>   name: "data"
>   type: "HDF5Data"
>   top: "data"
>   top: "label"
>   include {
>     phase: TRAIN
>   }
>   hdf5_data_param {
>     source: "examples/hdf5_classification/data/train.txt"
>     batch_size: 10
>   }
> }
> layer {
>   name: "fc1"
>   type: "InnerProduct"
>   bottom: "data"
>   top: "fc1"
>   param {
>     lr_mult: 1
>     decay_mult: 1
>   }
>   param {
>     lr_mult: 2
>     decay_mult: 0
>   }
>   inner_product_param {
>     num_output: 2
>     weight_filler {
>       type: "xavier"
>     }
>     bias_filler {
>       type: "constant"
>       value: 0
>     }
>   }
> }
> layer {
>   name: "loss"
>   type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
>   bottom: "fc1"
>   bottom: "label"
>   top: "loss"
> }
> I1119 01:29:02.520256 11910 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer data
> I1119 01:29:02.520277 11910 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer data
> I1119 01:29:02.520290 11910 net.cpp:411] data -> data
> I1119 01:29:02.520331 11910 net.cpp:411] data -> label
> I1119 01:29:02.520352 11910 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:80] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: examples/hdf5_classification/data/train.txt
> I1119 01:29:02.529341 11910 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:94] Number of HDF5 files: 1
> I1119 01:29:02.542645 11910 hdf5.cpp:32] Datatype class: H5T_FLOAT
> I1119 01:29:10.601307 11910 net.cpp:150] Setting up data
> I1119 01:29:10.612926 11910 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 10 3 256 256 (1966080)
> I1119 01:29:10.612963 11910 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 10 256 256 (655360)
> I1119 01:29:10.612969 11910 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 10485760
> I1119 01:29:10.612983 11910 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer fc1
> I1119 01:29:10.624948 11910 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer fc1
> I1119 01:29:10.625015 11910 net.cpp:454] fc1 <- data
> I1119 01:29:10.625039 11910 net.cpp:411] fc1 -> fc1
> I1119 01:29:10.645814 11910 net.cpp:150] Setting up fc1
> I1119 01:29:10.645864 11910 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 10 2 (20)
> I1119 01:29:10.645875 11910 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 10485840
> I1119 01:29:10.645912 11910 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer loss
> I1119 01:29:10.657094 11910 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer loss
> I1119 01:29:10.657133 11910 net.cpp:454] loss <- fc1
> I1119 01:29:10.657147 11910 net.cpp:454] loss <- label
> I1119 01:29:10.657163 11910 net.cpp:411] loss -> loss
> I1119 01:29:10.657189 11910 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer loss
> F1119 01:29:14.883095 11910 softmax_loss_layer.cpp:42] Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (10 vs. 655360) Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if softmax axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>     @     0x7f0652e1adaa  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f0652e1ace4  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f0652e1a6e6  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f0652e1d687  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f0653494219  caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer<>::Reshape()
>     @     0x7f065353f50f  caffe::Net<>::Init()
>     @     0x7f0653541f05  caffe::Net<>::Net()
>     @     0x7f06535776cf  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
>     @     0x7f0653577beb  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
>     @     0x7f0653578007  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
>     @     0x7f06535278b3  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
>     @           0x410831  caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
>     @           0x40a16b  train()
>     @           0x406908  main
>     @     0x7f065232cec5  (unknown)
>     @           0x406e28  (unknown)
>     @              (nil)  (unknown)
> Aborted
> ```

Basically the error is

```
softmax_loss_layer.cpp:42] Check failed: 
outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (10 vs. 655360) 
Number of labels must match number of predictions; 
e.g., if softmax axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), 
label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, 
with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
```

I am not able to understand why the number of labels expected is just same as my batch size. How exactly should I tackle this problem ? Is this a problem with my labeling method ?

Comment: I want to do a similar task see: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527898/caffe-from-classification-to-pixel-wise-prediction). I was wondering what your input images and ground_truth images looked like. Is it possible for you to provide that? Unlike you I want to do a regression task rather than a classification task. Would be nice if you could help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer tries to compare a prediction vector of 2 elements per input image to a label of size 256-by-256 per image.
This makes no sense.

**Root cause of the error:** I guess what you tired to do is to have a binary classifier applied to *each pixel* in the image. To that end you defined "fc1" as an `"InnerProduct"` layer  with `num_output=2`. However, the way caffe sees this is that you have a single binary classifier applied to the *entire* image. Thus caffe gives you a *single* binary prediction to the entire image.

**How to solve:** when working on pixel-wise predictions you no longer need to use `"InnerProduct"` layers and you have a "fully convolutional net". If you **replace** "fc1" with a conv layer (for instance a kernel that examine the 5-by-5 environment of each pixel and makes a decision according to this patch):

```
layer {
  name: "bin_class"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "bin_class"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2 # binary class output
    kernel_size: 5 # 5-by-5 patch for prediciton
    pad: 2 # make sure spatial output size equals size of label 
  }
}
```

Now applying `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` to `bottom: bin_class` and `bottom: label` should work.

Comment: I tried it but the problem still persists. Now my dimension are Data dimension from HDF5 (402, 3, 256, 256)
Label dimension from HDF5 (402, 1, 256, 256)

Comment: @Unni I changed my answer.

Comment: You are amazing! It was a silly mistake from me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Unni if you were silly you wouldn't be able to install caffe in the first place ;)

Comment: Would it be possible to not binary classify the pixels? as in having a depth image as ground truth? Could you use a similar approach? Something like this: [depth estimation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246526/caffe-depth-estimation) @Shai

Comment: @thigi as long as you have a discrete set of labels

Comment: Could you checkout the link I have mentioned in my las comment. That is my question. I would appreciate it if you might have some tips for me there.

Comment: @thigi I am sorry but I am not available for this in-depth consulting at the moment. If you have specific questions - please post them and I'm sure SO community (me included) will be able to provide some help.

Comment: If you would not have a discrete set of labels then you would just wanna do regression and therefore use an EuclideanLoss am I right?

Comment: Hi @Shai I had a similar problem but I solved it by using a specific padding value.
But when I input a image of different dimensions than the one it was trained on, my output size isn't the same as input. Any way I can tweak my architecture so that the input and output sizes are always the same?

Comment: @shubhamgoel27 consider using "Crop" layer